# How do I download an entire NFT collection, including metadata

Tags: nft, erc-721, meta-data

I want to download an entire collection, including the metadata. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need to use APIs for the specific website the NFT collection is hosted on. But there might be another easier solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opensea API to fetch all the collection stats including metadata. after fetching, you can easily dump them to an excel or any program of your choice

Link:
https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-collection-testnets

you will need a collection slug to fetch the collection. collection slug is unique identifier for the collection

Answer (score 0):

**To download an entire collection, including the metadata, you can use the following steps:**

Get a list of all the NFTs in the collection. You can do this using the OpenSea API or the Moralis API.

Download the metadata for each NFT. The metadata is usually stored on IPFS, so you can use a tool like ipfs get to download it.

Save the metadata to a file. You can save the metadata to a JSON file or a YAML file.

> Here is an example of how to download an entire NFT collection using
> the OpenSea API and the ipfs get command:

```
import requests

# Get the list of all the NFTs in the collection.
collection_slug = "boredapeyachtclub"
response = requests.get(f"https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections/{collection_slug}/assets")
nfts = response.json()

# Download the metadata for each NFT.
for nft in nfts:
    metadata_url = nft["metadata_url"]
    response = requests.get(metadata_url)
    metadata = response.json()

    # Save the metadata to a file.
    with open(f"{nft['token_id']}.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(metadata, f)
```

Once you have downloaded the metadata for all of the NFTs in the collection, you can store it in a database or a file system. You can then use the metadata to display the NFTs on your website or in your app.